# Need console bar that should display messages of my views.py

Tags: python, html, django

I am using django to build my application. here is my code:

```
def upload_sequence(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    sequence = request.POST.get("sequence")
    #sequence = sequence.replace("\n", "")
    file = request.FILES.get("file")

    try:
        if sequence:
            script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
            file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, "sequences.fasta")

            with open(file_path, "w") as f:
                f.write(sequence)
        elif file:
            script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
            file_path = os.path.join(script_dir, "sequences.fasta")
            with open(file_path, "wb") as f:
                for chunk in file.chunks():
                    f.write(chunk)

        calculate_features(file_path)
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error analyzing sequence: {e}")
        return JsonResponse({"status": "Error analyzing sequence"}, status=500)

    return redirect("results")
    
return render(request, "upload.html")
```

In this code: calculate_features(file_path) is a function which is displaying messages as:

```
completed_steps += 1
progress=int((completed_steps / total_steps) * 100)
progress_callback(f"Sequence {ID} uploaded successfully", progress)
```

I tried man methods to display these messages in html webpage in real time when the analysis runs, but none works. Please suggest me a good method for this.

Comment: did you try django messages https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/messages/

Comment: django messages are displaying when analysis is completed. not in real time when analysis is running. i want the messages to display in real time.

Comment: i want console bar like thing